# Spring Security SAML - Authenticating user without ADFS login page

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, adfs

I am using Spring Boot and using Spring Security SAML, I have been trying to authenticate the user with ADFS of my organisation. I have used Spring Security SAML Sample application (https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample) and able to authenticate the user using Sample app.

After that I have extended my application code referring this sample code and I am able to authenticate the user from my application.

Requirement in my application is:

1. I want to use my own login page (instead of ADFS login redirect) to capture the username and password
2. Pass on those credentials to ADFS server for authentication
3. Once user is authenticated, then redirect user to success page else redirect user to error page.

Till now what I have online seen references to ADFS login page only. Can anyone please guide or share pointers how I can use Spring Security SAML to integrate with ADFS without redirect to ADFS login page.

I know I can send the POST request on /adfs/services/trust/13/UsernameMixed URI and validate the user but this will be regular POST service. My question is how I can use Spring Security SAML Framework to achieve this?

Thanks,
Gourav.

Comment: @vladimír-schäfer can you please suggest a solution here?

Comment: I would question your requirement - why do you need their credentials? The whole point of SAML is to provide federated Security services like authentication, where some random app  (in this case your app) never sees the users credentials. Dealing with credentials is handed off the SAML IdP, which can provide any profile data you need (eg email addres, names, etc) on the SAMLResponse